# Touch screen detection placing video where touch occurred

Tags: javascript, html5-video

[image]

I am making a javascript rich project - which would include playing a motion graphic of a water ripple where the user had touched the screen.

How would I detect where the touch took place, and how would I place a html5 video in the middle of that region and auto play.

```
function is_touch_enabled() {
    return ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) ||
           ( navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ) ||
           ( navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0 );
}
```

How would I get the coordinates of the touch to place the video into that region

```
<p>
    Detect touch screen device
    using JavaScript
</p>
 
<p>
    If touch screen detected then display
    an image otherwise image will not
    display   
</p>
 
<div id="GFG"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
    function is_touch_enabled() {
        return ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) ||
               ( navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ) ||
               ( navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0 );
    }
 
    var src = "./orb2/water-ripple.mp4";
 
    if( is_touch_enabled() ) {
        var video = "<video width="320" height="176"><source src=" + src + " type="video/mp4"></video>";
    }
    else {
        var video = "";
    }
 
    document.getElementById('GFG').innerHTML = video;
</script>
```